# Security risk with HTML email template using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, razor

The client's current application has a an email functionality that sends out emails using a predefined HTML template. The application performs a  `Replace` on certain identified meta data elements like FName, LNAme.

They now want to redo this feature and allow for vendors to provide the HTML template that we would use and generate the full HTML body with right data from a `Model`

I looked at Razor and looks promising, but came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767002/how-dangerous-is-it-to-let-users-specify-razorengine-templates) SO article that informs of security risk to doing this as malicious code can be executed.

Are there any alternative to using Razor engine to generate HTML emails using a `.cshtml` file and supplying a `Model`?

I have used Velocity template before and not sure if NVelocity is still active and if it allows for conditional blocks to be placed in, Razor from read up allowed for conditional statements and would generate the HTML based on the evaluation of the condition.

Also would need the ability to send attachments and this is not on ASP.NET MVC project but `ASP.NET on Framework 4`

Comment: Take a look at dotliquid: http://dotliquidmarkup.org/

Comment: Plenty of template engines out there.  Go prototype them.

Comment: @Will: any recommendation from the vast collection?

Comment: I recommend you use a search engine, which has the latest and greatest indexed for you and available at your fingertips.  A couple days prototyping will tell you more than a hundred answers here.  Go forth, and be successful!